# how to layout a form for my quiz app and where to post to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I guess my problem is two-fold:

1. Right now I'm just displaying the question and answer, but giving the user no option to select his or her choice (the correct answer part were just to test that I can correctly set which answers are correct). I have nested models of Survey > Question > Answer

surveys/show.html.erb:

```
<ol>
  <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li class = 'question'><%= question.content  %>
  <ul>
    <% for answer in question.answers %>

    <li class = 'answer'>
    <%= answer.content %>
    <%if answer.correct_answer == true %>
    <span> <b>Correct Answer</b> </span>
    <% else %>
    <span> <b>Incorrect Answer</b></span>
    <% end%>
    </li>

    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </li>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

What would the form equivalent look like?

2. I can't decide on what action I should POST to. I would typically just submit to the create action in the same controller, but right now I'm using that action to create the survey. Do I just add another controller to post to or should I just add another action in the same controller and treat that as a sort of create action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, I'd have a `QuestionsController` and `AnswersController` this is because I know there may be other things I want to do with a question and answer via HTTP later.
I'd also have a table for storing the answer, question and user, which you could call answered_questions

```
class AnsweredQuestion
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end

class User
  has_many :answered_questions
end

class Question
  has_many :answered_questions
end

class Answer
  has_many :answered_questions
end

class Survey
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answered_questions, through: :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answered_questions
end

class SurveysController

  def answer_question
   @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
   @survey.update(answer_question_params) # not sure this is best way here, need to research a better way to create the nested resources rather than update
  end

  private
    def answer_question_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(answered_questions_attributes: [:answer_id, :question_id, :user_id])
    end
end
```

Then to allow your user select an answer, I'd have something like:

```
<ol>
  <%= form_for @survey, url: survey_answer_questions_path do |f| %>
  <% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
  <li class = 'question'><%= question.content  %>
  <ul>
     <%= f.fields_for :answered_questions do |aq| %>
       <%= aq.hidden_field :question, question.id %>
       <%= aq.hidden_field :user, current_user.id %>
       <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
         <%= aq.radio_button :answer, answer.id, answer.correct_answer %>
         <%= aq.label :answer, answer.content %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </li>
     <%= f.submit_button "Answer" %>
    <% end %>
</ol>
```

I'm doing this on the fly, couldn't really test if these are all correct, but it shows a general overview/approach I would take.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Why did you decide to separate Answer and AnsweredQuestion?

Comment: Because I'm guessing your app would have multiple users and you probably want to show the same questions to multiple users. Unless you have the bandwidth to be creating multiple questions and answers for each user of your app

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm still having a bunch of trouble figuring this out. I'm going to post another question that better encompasses what I'm struggling with particularly.